# Why is my Python nested while loop not working?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm learning Python and have a hard time understanding what's wrong with my logic in this nested loop.

```
numbers = [4, 3, 1, 3, 5]
sum = 0
    
while sum < 10:
 for n in numbers:
   sum += n
    
print(sum)
```

While sum is less than 10, iterate through the next object in a list and add it to the sum. Thus, it's supposed to print 11 (4+3+1+3, then it stops), but instead it prints 16. I have tried changing the order of loops:

```
for n in numbers:
 while sum < 10:
  sum += n
```

But then it prints 12, which further confuses me.

Can anybody please help? Thank you!

Comment: You simply do not understand how nested loops work.  Put enough `print()`  statements inside your loops to actually trace the execution.

Comment: Please avoid using the `built-in` `sum` as variable name.

Comment: [Tim's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793743/2550406) already explains it pretty well imo. I'd just like to add that in most such cases of confusion a debugger is very helpful. Since you are new to python you have perhaps not yet heard of that - if not, I recommend looking it up. It would allow you to see how the code affects the variables step by step.

Comment: Easier to run such small program in a visual platform - pythontutor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the outer `while` loop cannot test the `sum` value until the inner loop has totally completed.  You would need something like this:

```
for n in numbers:
   sum += n
   if sum >= 10:
      break
```

As for your second sample, trace through it:

```
for n in numbers:
 while sum < 10:
  sum += n
```

To start with, `n` will be set to 4.  You then stay in the inner loop for a while.  `sum` will become 4, then 8, then 12, then that loop exits.  As the outer loop goes through the rest of the numbers, `sum` is already greater than 10, so the `while` loop never runs.

You can't use two nested loops to accomplish your task.  It must be one loop with an extra exit condition.